# GACK response from SOAP Tooling API runTestsAsynchronous method

Tags: tooling-api, gack

I'm attempting to call the [`runTestsAsynchronous(classids, suiteids, maxFailedTests)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/intro_soap_overview.htm#runTestsAsynchronous_example) method on the SOAP Tooling API as per the linked documentation and the example in [ApexTestQueueItem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_apextestqueueitem.htm). In both cases, one of `classids` and `suiteids` should be null.

> Either a `classids` or a `suiteids` parameter is mandatory for `runTestsAsynchronous`, but only one of the two is required. To provide only one, specify the other as null.

Trying this directly with a SOAP request:

## Request

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:tooling.soap.sforce.com">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <urn:SessionHeader>
         <urn:sessionId>00D700000000000!AQoAQPXaGU_NotMyRealSessionId_0rE.eDPEidnsqaSrRRFiq1oYGwqeSQrr9cctjcy6SKCR6cVHyaN</urn:sessionId>
      </urn:SessionHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:runTestsAsynchronous>
         <!-- <urn:classids>?</urn:classids> -->
         <urn:suiteids>05F700000000001EAA</urn:suiteids>
         <urn:maxFailedTests>1</urn:maxFailedTests>
      </urn:runTestsAsynchronous>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

## Response

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Invalid parameter value "1" for parameter "id". Error Id: 823319557-60758 (-1940664859)</faultstring>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that passing an empty string for the unused parameter avoids the error. E.g.

## Request

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:tooling.soap.sforce.com">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <urn:SessionHeader>
         <urn:sessionId>00D700000000000!AQoAQPXaGU_NotMyRealSessionId_0rE.eDPEidnsqaSrRRFiq1oYGwqeSQrr9cctjcy6SKCR6cVHyaN</urn:sessionId>
      </urn:SessionHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:runTestsAsynchronous>
         <urn:classids></urn:classids>
         <urn:suiteids>05F700000000001EAA</urn:suiteids>
         <urn:maxFailedTests>1</urn:maxFailedTests>
      </urn:runTestsAsynchronous>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

## Response

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="urn:tooling.soap.sforce.com">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <runTestsAsynchronousResponse>
         <result>7077000002eZgf2</result>
      </runTestsAsynchronousResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

## Alternative Request using nil

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:tooling.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <urn:SessionHeader>
         <urn:sessionId>00D700000000000!AQoAQPXaGU_NotMyRealSessionId_0rE.eDPEidnsqaSrRRFiq1oYGwqeSQrr9cctjcy6SKCR6cVHyaN</urn:sessionId>
      </urn:SessionHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:runTestsAsynchronous>
         <urn:classids xsi:nil="true" />
         <urn:suiteids>05F700000000001EAA</urn:suiteids>
         <urn:maxFailedTests>1</urn:maxFailedTests>
      </urn:runTestsAsynchronous>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```